# Next.js 11: Cannot read property 'canonicalBase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Have a problem after updating from Next.js **10.0.2** to **11.0.1**
After the update I can't start a project, because of

```
Cannot read property 'canonicalBase' of undefined
```

**_app.tsx** Next imports:

```
import App, { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { Router } from 'next/router';
```

**_document.tsx** Next import:

```
import Document, { DocumentProps, Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
```

Have somebody had the same issue?

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace please? I will try to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**nrwl/nx** <v12.8.0 doesn`t support **next.js** v11. Update resolved the issue.

Release note: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/releases/tag/12.8.0